# Grails object relationships that have an owning side - why?

Tags: grails

While one advantage to having an owning side in a Grails object relationship is to have cascaded deletes, I was wondering what are some other advantages or reasons we might want to declare owning sides in Grails object relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `belongsTo` property is really just a simple way to manage cascading strategies.  The docs at http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html and http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#ormdsl discuss more details but the short of it is just that, managing how things cascade.

Answer (score 1):

I have some history with Grails and one thing that pops up in every project is to that GORM bites you a lot. If you can't justify benefits of owning sides of relations, probably you don't want to have them. Keep GORM model as simple as possible.

Comment: "If you can't justify benefits of owning sides of relations, probably you don't want to have them." - While that is true enough, it is true of every feature of the framework.  If a feature isn't doing something for you, don't use it.

Comment: Well it's maybe true for every feature but GORM and especially `hasMany` tag can keep developers busy for few hours without good reason.

Comment: I agree with you.  My point is that your comment is almost like saying "don't use a feature that you don't have a use for" or "if the feature doesn't yield a net positive, don't use it".  No one would argue with those.

Comment: Ok, got it. I just spend lot of time trying to fully understand, debug and explain to others `hasMany` and `belongsTo` Grails relations (`hasOne` is funny one ;)). It's just wasted time. That's why I suggest to avoid it instead of understand it.